# how to replace &amp as real ''&'' symbol in react native

Tags: react-native

How can I convert '&amp' into '**&**' symbol and show it as '**&**' symbol instead of '&amp' in my application? anyway to do this, or any library can be used? in React Native

Comment: what language are using to create your application

Comment: React Native and PHP @GeorgeSMulbahII

Comment: You can use the [html-entities](https://github.com/mdevils/html-entities#readme) library. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70057329/decodeuricomponent-in-react/70057389#70057389

Answer (score -1):

if you are using react-native then try this

```
<Text> &#38;</Text>
```